# excel assign the value and formatting of a cell

Tags: excel

I want to assign  the cell F2 to have the same value as the cell A2 and also the same formatting so that when I update A2, then F2 gets updated as well.

Backstory: I have a whole bunch of Pivot Tables and I want to add them to Pivot charts but apparently pivot charts don't include grand totals so you gotta create new tables identical to pivot tables and then create a new chart which can include the tables with grant totals. My pivot tables have cell number formatting and other formatting that I was hoping there would be an efficient way to preserve.

Comment: Would you be predefining the formatting of A2 or the formatting of A2 can change?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Perhaps you can tell me solutions for both? I was hoping to have the flexibility to change the formatting but I can live with a rigid formatting if I must.

Comment: The reson why I asked is because for dynamic formatting, you will have to use VBA I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using a calculated field to get the total?  The PivotChart will graph that.

Comment: @PaigeLo I am trying to add the calculated field but I don't know how to get it take the values of Grand total. I don't know what "Formula" to give it in the "Insert Calculated Field" pop up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For fixed format**:
Enter in F2 the formula `=A2`. Then copy A2, and in F2 Paste special -> Formats. This should work .

[image]

**For varying format**:
There is no event for a change in format.
To copy the format from A2 to F2 each time the format of A2 changes, a workaround is given [To track style changes in Excel 2007/2010 using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126945/to-track-style-changes-in-excel-2007-2010-using-vba). You would use this to detect changes, and if needed, copy and paste format via VBA.

Comment: thanks! That's great. Is there an short cut way to do this for an entire table or do I have to do this cell by cell? ... I am guessing writing a VBA macro will be the way to go here.

Comment: @Amatya - You can paste formats for a whole range at once. Try copy, select a range, paste special -> formats. VBA will work similarly (you can record a macro while you perform the operations by hand, and see what is the resulting code).