# Cells format event/hook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I worked on VSTO C# Excel 2013. I tried and searched many approaches to find a way to trigger more events.

One of the important events I need is, cells formatted event (changing background color, merging cells.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event.  Your main events are for `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects.  Intellisense is presumably giving them all to you.  If not, check out the [MS reference for `Worksheet` events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet_events.aspx).  There is a similar list for `Workbook`.  These are also the same as the events available within the VBA editor inside Excel.

If you want to cheat and make an event, it involves watching all of the cells and detecting the change yourself using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.  See related: [How to detect changes in cell format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342408/how-to-detect-changes-in-cell-format)

Note that approach will not work if you are trying to detect format changes that are effected by your code instead of the user (unless of course you are using `Select` in your code which would be inadvisable).

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to ask is there a way to walkaround on merging events. Neither sheetChange nor selectionChange will be fired when doing merging cells.

Comment: You should be able to do the same sort of trick as `Worksheet_SelectionChanged` and then watch the `MergeCells` property.  By watch, I mean: build a dictionary, store entries and look for changes.  It will be `True` if the cells are merged.  Alternatively, you could go through and make a list of `MergeArea.Address` entries where `MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1`.  All of those will indicate the presence/change to a merged cell.