# Event triggered when cell formatting changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which *highlights* the row of the table containing the `Target` cell based on a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.
My macro changes the `.Pattern`, `.TintAndShade` and `.Color`properties of `tableRow.Interior`, effectively bucket filling them with a colour *but only temporarily*: when a cell of a different table row is selected, the macro highlights that row and restores the first row back to its original formatting. I have a `Public formatLog()` array declared which I save the formatting to before I bucket fill, and which I read back when reseting the fills.

I would like another portion of code to trigger when the formatting of the selected range is changed (specifically any of the listed `.Interior.[...]` values), but only manually. So maybe something which I can use `Application.EnabledEvents = False` to turn off when my Macro is formatting, but which is triggered by the user doing the same thing. I.e. a `Worksheet_FormatChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event to monitor any format changes in the worksheet.

#### Why this approach?

The easiest way would be to use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` trigger to record the current cell formatting, compare it to how it was before, and then if it's changed I simply put the new value in my `formatLog()` so that when I click away the de-hilighting code resets the cell to the new format saved in the log.

i.e. consider 4 cases

**Case A,** no event to log changes in formatting

`A1:D1` is initially filled Green. When I select `A1`,the colour of `A1:D1` is saved, then it is all bucket filled yellow by my macro. I change `A1` to Red fill and click in a new row `A2`. Now the macro looks at the saved values in `A1:D1` spots they're all Green, and fills `A1:D1` with Green like it was.

*Result: `A1` Red fill isn't saved*

**Case B,** use the log in combination with a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to record changes in colour

`A1:D1` is green as above. `A1` is selected and its location `t` noted. Situation as before; *the colour of `A1:D1` is saved, then it is all bucket filled yellow by my macro. I change `A1` to Red fill and click away*. This time `SelectionChange` triggers, pointing to the last known target location `t` which was `A1`; code sees "`A1 was Green, now it's Red`" and it updates the `formatLog()` to reflect this. Finally, when I click out of the 1st row and into `A2`, the macro restores `A1:D1` using the new format for `A1`

*Result: Red format saved(sometimes)*

**Case C, ignore yellow fill**

Case B works fine, unless instead of filling `A1` Red, I just click away. Then my `SelectionChange` is triggered, looks in the last target `t` (A1), says `Oh look, A1 was Green, now it's` **`yellow`** and saves that to the log. But the yellow fill was done by the macro, not the user. That's clearly incorrect.

Instead I can tell the selection change to only update the log if the formatting is not yellow - which leads to **Case 4**, what if I manually fill the cell with the same colour as the macro did. How can I tell when the fill was human or computer? This is where I would like to use `SelectionChange` but can't!

Well one way is to have a different `Worksheet_FormatChange` event, which is disabled while the macro runs, but is triggered by user formatting. If you've followed all that, then that's why I ask for an new event. I'm aware similar questions have been asked: [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342408/how-to-detect-changes-in-cell-format) but I'm relatively new to VBA and can't understand enough to apply the answer to my problem.